# How to display a button after 5 minutes in ASP.net (.aspx)?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I am fairly new to the ASP.NET so is there a way to make a button visible after a certain time?

```
<asp:Button   ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click here"  OnClick="btn_Click" Visible="False" />
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/site...." );
        }
```

Comment: Do you really want to use ASP.NET? You can do very easily with JS

Comment: @RezaJenabi How can I do with JS? Thank you

Comment: You cannot do this from code-behind: once the HTML is sent to the browser, the server cannot access it anymore. You *need* (client-side) javascript for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the following code can help you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function show()
    {
        document.getElementById("Button1").style.visibility = "visible";
    }

    function hide()
    {
        document.getElementById("Button1").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

    window.onload = function()
    {
        hide();
        setTimeout('show()', 30000);
    }

</script>
```

the code at the bottom of the page to run after the page is created